# how to remotely control raspberry pi gpio

Tags: python

I'm doing a face recognition project that uses opencv and python to recognize a person's face on a pc. Now, my goal is to use a raspberry pi to access one of my gpio ports, and when One face was detected in my pc then to turn on a led. My problem is how can I connect my pc to a raspberry pi and use the code that runs on my pc to run the raspberry pi gpio?

Comment: This is too broad of a question from here.  There's LOTS of information on how to control GPIO on Raspberry Pi.  If you've tried something specific and hit a specific problem, give us some details.

Answer (score 2):

Use pigpio or GPIOZero with python. That allows a python program running anywhere to connect to your RPi and change the status of GPIO pins.

[GPIOZero remote control](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/remote_gpio.html)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is make your Raspberry Pi as a server using Flask or LAMP and communicate with your PC. If you are using LAMP(Linux-Apache-MySQL-PHP) to create server, you can use [WiringPi](http://wiringpi.com). You can also use [WiringPi-Python](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi-Python) to communicate to GPIO pins from PC.